# How can I stop "scrollIntoView" when the screen reaches a reference?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I stop the scroll Into View when the screen reach the reference (inside the method scroll) ?
(When the screen reaches its reference, I scroll a little bit up and the code atomatcaly come back to the reference)

```js
interface Props {
    section: number
}
const Home = ({ section }: Props) => {

    const sectionRef1: any = useRef(React.createRef());
    const sectionRef2: any = useRef(React.createRef());

    const scroll = (ref: any) => {
        ref.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'smooth',
            block: 'start',
        });
    };

    function scrollToSection(section: number) {
        if (section === 1) {
            scroll(sectionRef1);
        }
        else if (section === 2) {
            scroll(sectionRef2);
        }
        else if (section === 3) {
            //TODO: active button
        }
    }

    scrollToSection(section);

    return (
        <div>
            <div ref={sectionRef1} />
            <Carrousel></Carrousel>
            <div ref={sectionRef2} className="margin_top_portrait" />
            <Portrait></Portrait>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Home;
```

I'm afraid that this funcion will never finish ... and it's asynchronous.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run the scroll method only when the section changes, you can use the useEffect hook of react:

```
useEffect(() => {
    scrollToSection(section);
}, [section]);
```

This will execute the `scrollToSection` method the first time the component is mounted and every time the `section` prop changes.